# Conjugation preserves representation?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.  The action $\varphi_g$ of $G$ on $H$ by conjugation may not preserve a representation, because $h$ and $\varphi_g(h)  = ghg^{-1}$ are not necessarily in the same conjugacy class of $H$ (even though they are in the same class in $G$).

Therefore, given an irreducible representation $\rho$ of $H$, we may have $\rho \circ \varphi_g$ different from $\rho$.  Is it true that $\varphi_h$ for $h \in H$ "preserves" the representation $\rho$, in the sense that $\varphi_g \circ \rho$ is the same map as $\rho$?

Comment: There isn't such an action unless $H$ is normal. It's true that $\varphi_h, h \in H$ (now $G$ is irrelevant) preserves $\rho$ in the sense that $\varphi_h \circ \rho$ is isomorphic to $\rho$, but they're not literally the same map.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks.  Hmm, are the irreducible representations enumerated in the character table unique or just unique up to isomorphism?  I think it's the former, but not sure.

Comment: Up to isomorphism.